# Angular Service Worker can't fetch SVG files

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I use a service worker in my Angular app. All the files in my assets folder are cached, as declared in my `ngsw-config.json` file.

```
{
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
}
```

I have .svg and .png files in my assets folder. When I build my app for production and visit my site for the first time, eveything works fine, but as soon as I reload the page, I get the following error in my console.

[image]

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork)**

This problem only occurs when the browser tries to fetch a .svg file. It works fine with .png files

I load all my .svg file inside of an `<img>` tag.

I wonder if I did something wrong, or if it is a problem with the Angular Service Worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, consider using the svg files inline and not like that:
`<img src="assets/imgs/img.svg" />`

Hope that helps

Comment: I ended up doing that

Comment: Sad but true, also means that any icon registry icons can't be loaded either.